# Run tasks in parallel way inside aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to figure out the best solution to increase the speed of my lambda function by running my code in parallel as always my loop doing same thing over and over again is there a solution ? or way?

Comment: also very interested.

Answer (score 0):

This is prime example for multithreading.

Taken from [python std lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html):

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

You can easily adapt it for your needs.

One caveat is that you cannot open more than 1000 threads in AWS Lambda, so be mindful of that.

Comment: Oh this is maybe what I need, Thank you.

Comment: I also heard that SQS might be a solution but can't make it work ? have you ever tried that ?

Comment: @habdie SQS will work too, but in case of simple HTTP request it would be overkill imo

Comment: Despite using this I still get a time out issue, can I show you my code tell me what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: @habdie I can give you one hint right away - give your Lambda more memory, at least 512-1024 Mb. Threads are CPU heavy, and more memory gives you more CPU proportionally. Usually it helps.